# Is it recommended to use Node.js for an online room booking web application?

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, database-design, web-applications, architecture

I have to build a web application for booking Hostel rooms online.
Hostel has 78 independent clusters consisting of 11 rooms. So it has total 858 rooms.

A user can take a room as an individual or in a group of 2-11 persons.
So mainly there are 3 entities in the system: User, Room and Group.
He just have to sign-up on the system and can join a group or can take a room.

Registrations starts a week prior to actual allotment day i.e. user can register but can't book a room.
On the actual allotment day, admin of the group will book rooms for all the group members on first come first serve basis. The allotment process hardly takes 30 mins. There are 80-90 users simultaneously online on the website to book the rooms. Last year we hosted this app on a shared web hosting but on the start of allotment process, the site was down. Nobody was able to log-in and book rooms.
Existing app is developed in PHP.

So this is the whole story. Now we want to re-write the whole app using MVC architecture. I was thinking to use Node.js.
Which technology stack would be best suitable for this application?
Also can somebody point me in the right direction for choosing an architecture for the app?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use MVC with Nodejs, you could give [Sails.js](http://sailsjs.org/#!/) a try. I've heard some nice things about it lately. It is a MVC framework, supporting many databases. I've used it in a small project and was quite happy with it.

However, you could also consider the very popular [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/) framework, even though it is not a real MVC Framework.

An alternative to Nodejs could also be [RoR](http://rubyonrails.org/) (if you're into Ruby) or [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) (Python), just to name a few of the mainstream ones.